# Are IdGeneratorStrategy.Identity values reused after a jdo has been deleted

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using Google App Engine.

If a Long key field is generated by IdGeneratorStrategy.Identity and then the object is deleted from the datastore, is there any chance of the key being used again by a different object of the same class?

> papercrane on reddit writes:
>
> > The documentation for
> >     GenerationType.IDENTITY says that it
> >     means the persistence provider (the
> >     database) will provide the unique ID.
> >     So it is entirely up to your database
> >     software if it decides to reuse IDs
> >     from deleted records. Without knowing
> >     anything else about your problem I'd
> >     say it is possible, but I can't think
> >     of any good reason for a database
> >     server to keep track of which IDs are
> >     in use and recycle old ones. That
> >     seems like a lot of overhead for very
> >     little benefit.

---

> And Mark Ross on Google Groups writes
>   on how GAE identities are generated:
>
> > Since the datastore in prod is
> >     comprised of multiple back-ends, we
> >     use a sharded counter approach to dole
> >     out IDs so that we don't have to worry
> >     about different back-ends handing out
> >     the same id. So, back-end A may be
> >     working from a pool of IDs ranging
> >     from 0 to 100 and back-end B may be
> >     working from a pool of IDs ranging
> >     from 101 to 200, and so on. If your
> >     inserts hit different datastore
> >     back-ends you'll get IDs that jump
> >     around a bit. You can depend on these
> >     IDs being unique, but not
> >     monotonically increasing.

I now think that it is very unlikely that Identity values are reused but it would still be good to have a clear definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine will never reuse IDs for a given kind and parent. In fact, I think you'll be hard pressed to find a database that does - keeping a simple counter is far, far simpler than trying to figure out which IDs are still in use, and with 64 bits, you're not going to run out of IDs.